# Is there a way to secure folders in ColdFusion, without the use of Application.cfc in every folder?

Tags: coldfusion, application.cfc, coldfusion-7

The only way I can figure how to secure folders, is to include a basic Application.cfc in every-single-one including sub-folders.

If file `/test/thisfile.cfm` is secure and sends a user not logged in to the login page, however the folder `/test/test2/` must also have an Application.cfc or a user could directly go to `test/test2/thatfile.cfm` without a problem.

I know there has to be a better way than this, I'm just not sure what it is and everything on Google is telling me to use the "Login Wizard" or to install a framework. Neither of which is an option for me.

Another consideration, this must work in MX 7 unfortunately. If there are better options in CF 9, then I would be happy to hear them, but the priority is MX 7.

Comment: If your folder doesn't have an Application.cfm or cfc, CF should be going to the next folder level and looking for one there. Normally you would have to to try and NOT have a directory use the application.cfm by making an empty application.cfm in that specific directory.  Do you have an Application.cfm in your root?

Comment: Application.cfc in the root is the one that I wanted to use to do the login check and send non-logged in users to the login page. However, I was able to go directly to sub folders and view files without a problem.

Comment: A single Application.cfc (or Application.cfm) at the top level folder will cascade down, unless there is an Application.cf~ in any directory between that file and the top-level.

If there is definitely no Application.cf~ file in the way then your Application.cfc has missing/incorrect logic to prevent access to the relevant files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without an Application.cfc file or an MVC Framework, you can manually start each "secure" CFM file with a check for a session variable:

```
<cfif (NOT structKeyExists( session, "isLoggedIn" )) OR (session.isLoggedIn = false)>
    <cflocation url="/" />
</cfif>
```

Of course, this is a very laborious and not easily maintained practice, but sometimes you just work with what you got.

Comment: You can just put this bit of code once in application.cfc onRequestStart

Comment: I don't think this in and of itself should be marked as the answer.  We should be revisiting this statement, from a comment above: "Application.cfc in the root [...] However, I was able to go directly to sub folders and view files without a problem".  If this is the case, you're not telling us the full story, and something else is afoot.  Let's fix this *properly*.  Can you expand your question to include relevant directory structure and locations of: a) Application.cfc; b) files that *do* respect it; c) files that *don't* respect it.